# How to implement a custom sorting algorithm to accept any type in python?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, sorting

If I have to implement the sort, how can I make it accept any type of data (a list, string, set, dictionary or my own class type) and sort it? (I have done it for list, though). I'm new to OOPS and I couldn't understand much of source code of sorted(), which is written in 'C'.

**EDITS**

Here is the code:

```
class InsertionSort:    

    def insertion_sort(it):

        for i in range(len(it)):
            j = i
            while j > 0 and it[j] < it[j - 1]:
                it[j], it[j-1] = it[j-1], it[j]
                j -= 1

        return it


it_ints = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

sorted_ints = InsertionSort.insertion_sort(it_ints)
```

Now, what if I wanna pass other data structures? I could convert them to list as one of the answers say, but, how to sort dictionary or other types of data

**I'm looking for something like Comparable of Java
in Python to implement**

PS: I'm actually doing Algorithms course on Coursera which is in JAVA. I'm trying to analyze the lectures there and re-write programs in python, particularly with class implementation.
Need help

Answer (score 1):

Now that you've mentioned that you already have a function to sort list than why not try this?

```
  def yourSortingFunction(items):
    #now that you're expecting them to be list:
    items = list(items)

    //your sorting code
```

P.S: even sorted() function in python 3.x returns a list of sorted elements when you pass(list, set, string) and since you asked about these 3 in your question I'm suggesting this solution.

Comments and edits are most welcome. I'm new to StackOverflow (and coding).

Comment: Yes, I thought about it. But it's not flexible. If you wanna sort a dictionary based on values, or some custom type of values, say file object, then not possible